# Save button doesn't work in management program

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void saveEmployeeButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (validPasswords()) {
        try {
            if (employee != null) {
                updateEmployee();
                employee.updateEmployeeInDB();
            } else {
                if (imageChanged) {
                    employee = new Employee(firstNameTextField.getText(),
                            lastNameTextField.getText(), eType.getValue().toString(),
                            phoneNumberTextField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(salaryTextField.getText().toString()),
                            birthday.getValue(), imageFile, pwField.getText());

                } else {
                    if (Validation.emptyCheck(firstNameTextField.getText()) == false) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the first name");
                    } else {
                        employee = new Employee(
                                firstNameTextField.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText(),
                                eType.getValue().toString(), phoneNumberTextField.getText(),
                                Integer.parseInt(salaryTextField.getText().toString()), birthday.getValue(),
                                pwField.getText());
                    }
                }
                errMsgLabel.setText("");
                employee.insertIntoDB();
            }
            SceneChanger sc = new SceneChanger();
            sc.changeScene(event, "Employee.fxml", "Employee");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            errMsgLabel.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method for save

```
public void updateEmployeeInDB() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bakery", "root", "a3756421");
        String sql = "UPDATE employee SET eName1=?,eName2=?,eType=?,phoneNumber=?,eSalary=?,birthday=?,imageFile=?" + "WHERE eId = ?";
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        Date db = Date.valueOf(birthday);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, eId);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, eName1); 
        preparedStatement.setString(3, eName2);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, eType);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, phoneNumber);
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, eSalary);
        preparedStatement.setDate(7, db);
        preparedStatement.setString(8, imageFile.getName());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        preparedStatement.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
        if (preparedStatement != null)
            preparedStatement.close();

    }

}
```

This is the method for update employee

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    eId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   eName1 VARCHAR(30),
    eName2 VARCHAR(30),
    eType VARCHAR(30),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(12),
     eSalary INT,
     birthday DATE,
     imageFile VARCHAR(100)
);
```

This is the table I'm using in the database

Even when I press the save button, not only it doesn't update into the database but also it doesn't change the scene.
I have checked whether the save button has a problem with the scene-builder but it was all fine.

Comment: Did you check what error was printed from your database update method?

Comment: There was no error printed

Comment: Are you sure about that? The prepared statement looks wrong, you set id as the first parameter but uses it as the last one in the query string. Maybe you should use the debugger.

Comment: will try, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preparedStatement has wrong order. You are setting id first but in query It is last. I also changed sql query as there is no need for +

```
String sql = "UPDATE employee SET eName1=?,eName2=?,eType=?,phoneNumber=?,eSalary=?,birthday=?,imageFile=? WHERE eId = ?";
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    Date db = Date.valueOf(birthday);

    preparedStatement.setString(1, eName1); 
    preparedStatement.setString(2, eName2);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, eType);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, phoneNumber);
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, eSalary);
    preparedStatement.setDate(6, db);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, imageFile.getName());
    preparedStatement.setInt(8, eId); // THIS IS LAST NOW
```

Comment: it worked thank you, do you happen to know what to do if the id doesn't show up in tableview?

Comment: @FrankSeo What do you mean by "doesn't show up in tableview"

Comment: I have fixed it but now the entire table won't show up